# My comments are disappearing

Tags: bug

At least two comments I left today have disappeared. For the first, I figured I just forgot to submit the comment, but it seems extremely unlikely that I'd have forgotten to submit two.

One was a comment on Will's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/how-should-one-use-write18-with-bibtex/4488#4488) to one of my questions. The other was a comment on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/whats-a-good-way-to-write-x-does-not-divide-y/4476#4476).

Comment: The same thing happened to me, so maybe I didn't forget to submit after all ...

Comment: Funnily enough, I reposted that answer after it disappeared for exactly the same reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that this hasn't recurred so am closing to avoid it resurfacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just [moved datacenters](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) so it's possible, albeit strange, that some of your comments would go to the old datacenter instead of the new one.

But if you can leave comments at all, that implies you are at the new datacenter -- the old sites are read only.